# VBox Debian/Ubuntu - Automatically mount shared folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, debian, debian-jessie

I've searched some tutorials and posts - **how to automatically mount shared folder in Virtual Box** (using version 5.0.24) for Debian (using version 8.0 ). I think that Ubuntu's process is the same.

I've setup my fstab and also added `vboxsf` into modules, but folder still didn't shared or I was still getting errors. I was also thinking of using **rc.local** way, **but this is not the right  way** to setup your automatically shared folder on system boot.

After this, I decided to write my own answer on this question - **How to make your shared folder automatically mounted on system boot up?**

Answer (score 1):

## Host setup

First make sure **you've installed Guest Additions** on your virtual machine. If you didn't see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm). Go to Virtual Box, your virtual machine and click Settings.

[image]

Create a folder within host (using Windows 7) or choose one. Remember the **Folder name** we will use it when setting up our shared folder in guest (Debian / Ubuntu).

## 1. Auto mount using VBox

#### **Wait!** Auto-mount?

**I see "Auto-mount" option there!** This option will make your shared folder mounted automatically on guest boot. This is what we want! **BUT**.

Checking **auto-mount** will mount your **shared** folder into `/media/<your folder name>` in your guest.

TIP: Type `df` command into console to see where is your shared folder mounted.

If you are fully satisfied with this way. You're done. You don't have to read this post further.

---

## 2. Auto mount to custom location

Mount your shared folder into **custom** location. Such as www folder of your Apache or nginx web server etc.

**Always rember to disable Auto-mount option in VBox settings. Do not forget.**

[image]

Launch your virtual machine. Remember to **create folder** in guest before mounting.

*Adding mount command into rc.local could cause problems. Better to not do it. Use fstab instead.*

#### Add module

Go to `sudo nano /etc/modules` And add this to the end of the file

```
vboxsf
vboxvfs
vboxadd
```

#### Add command to fstab

Go to `sudo nano /etc/fstab` And add this line to the end of the file `<your folder name> <your custom path to the folder> vboxsf default 0 0`

---

Now you can **reboot your virtual machine** to see changes.

If you have any suggestions, please leave a comment or edit my answer!

Comment: Encountered Ubuntu 21.10 not wanting to boot with error `Failed to mount /home/<user_name>/guest_shared. Dependency failed for Local File Systems`. The entry in my fstab looks like `host_shared /home/<user_name>/guest_shared/ vboxsf default 0 0`. The host_shared directory is located within the same directory as the rest of the VM's files (.vdi, .vbox, etc). Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

To mount a shared folder using the vboxsf filesystem, we first need to make sure some prerequisites are met as follows:

**#1 Guest Additions**

This could already be installed during the installation of certain versions of Ubuntu. You may check via the link below:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/169024/how-can-i-tell-if-the-virtualbox-guest-additions-were-installed-on-an-ubuntu-vm

**#2  VM settings for Shared Folders**
[image: Key parameter is Name]

Note that the name of the shared folder depends on the key parameter inside the picture above, which I have chosen the name to be "Public".

In the picture, the host folder is /tmp. But this may not be a good idea since this folder will be automatically deleted by the system upon shutdown. You should choose another folder once you are comfortable with all the steps shown here.

**#3 Create a shared folder in your VM's home directory**

$ mkdir ~/shared

This serves as the mountpoint.

It is best choose a mountpoint in your home folder. This is the solution for newer versions of Linux (in which case the /media/sf_Public mountpoint does not work).

**#3 Configure fstab**

Put the following line in our /etc/fstab file:

```
name_of_share   /path/to/mountpoint   vboxsf   defaults  0   0
```

Replace name_of_share and /path/to/mountpoint with your individual setup:

- name_of_share: Public (if you have used the name shown in the above picture)
- /path/to/mountpoint: the folder for the mountpoint created in the preceding step.

Now reboot the VM.

**Troubleshooting**

- Remember you need to be a member of the group vboxsf.
- If you are using a recent release of Virtual Box, you may already have all these steps automatically done. If that were the case, this shared folder will be mounted to the guest directory /media//sf_<name_of_share> accessible to all users who had been made member of the group vboxsf.

Important:
But if all else fails, then you can try the link below

https://askubuntu.com/questions/252853/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder-at-startup